# Number Theory: The fundamental theorem of arithmetic. How to find out whether or not numbers are prime.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $m\ge 2$ be a composite integer.

a. Show that there is a prime number $p$ such that p|m and $p\le\sqrt{m}$

b. Use what you have found in part (a) to check whether or not $473$ is a prime
number.

c. Is $487$ prime?

I don't know how to solve this/express this in math.

Comment: This all sounds like maths to me. If (a) were false, all the prime factors of $m$ would be quite big wouldn't they?

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how to word this in like mathematical notation. I just wrote out an explanation in common language, but the assignment requires that it be written mathematically, using variables, like a proof.

Comment: Then write it out in "common language", and we'll help you beat it into shape.

Comment: I *think* (am most likely wrong) that since p is less than or equal to the square root of m, that in order to find out if something is factorable, you square root that number m, and since the squares of the numbers I'm working with aren't that large, just pick out the primes from 2 all the way up to the closest prime to the square root of m.  Then divide them one by one by m to see if m is a composite or prime number?

Comment: I think this is called the _sieve of eratosthenes_...

Comment: You could try dividing 487 by 2. If that's not an integer, try dividing 487 by 3, then 5, then 7, then 11, then 13, then 17, etc. By the time you try dividing it by 251, it should be quite clear that you could have stopped earlier.

Comment: "I think (am most likely wrong) that since p is less than or equal to the square root of m" you are meant to prove $p\le\sqrt m$, not assume it. "in order to find out if something is factorable" in order to find out if $m$ is factorable. "the closest prime to the square root of m" the largest prime not exceeding $\sqrt m$. "Then divide them one by one by m" no, you don't divide the primes by $m$, you divide $m$ by the primes.

Answer (score 2):

Let $n$ be a composite number. By definition, there exist two other numbers, $a, b \in \mathbb N$, such that $ab = n$ and $1 < a, b < n$ (otherwise $n$ would be prime). Now, both $a$ and $b$ can't be larger than $\sqrt n$: in  that case, $n = ab < \sqrt{n} \sqrt{n} = n$, a contradiction. So one of them is smaller than $\sqrt n$. Let's say it's $a$.

If $a$ is prime, we  are done. If not, we factorise it further and it's okay too - all of its divisor are of course smaller than $a$ itself.

For b) and c) you have to check for prime divisors smaller than 23.